# center an indicator view in an alertcontroller programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints, autoresizingmask

I am trying to center an activity indicator in an alert controller programmatically but am not seeing the expected outcome.

Attempt:

```
import NVActivityIndicatorView

public func displayActivityAlertWithCompletion(ViewController: UIViewController, pending: UIAlertController, completionHandler: @escaping ()->())
{

    //create an activity indicator
    let indicator = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: (pending.view.frame.width/2) - 25 , y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))


    //indicator.clipsToBounds = true
    indicator.type = .ballScaleMultiple
    indicator.autoresizingMask = \[.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight\]
    indicator.color = UIColor(rgba: Palette.loadingColour)



    //add the activity indicator as a subview of the alert controller's view
    pending.view.addSubview(indicator)
    indicator.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    // required otherwise if there buttons in the UIAlertController you will not be able to press them
    indicator.startAnimating()



    ViewController.present(pending, animated: true, completion: completionHandler)
}
```

[image]

Comment: what are you seeing?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ sorry I had added a picture but the syntax got messed up around the code, re-added it

Comment: what value you are getting from this `pending.view.frame.width`? From where  you are calling the method `displayActivityAlertWithCompletion`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing lies in this line:

```
let indicator = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: (pending.view.frame.width/2) - 25 , y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
```

At this point your `pending` alert controller is **not** yet presented, and it's frame is not updated.

You will have to update the `frame` of the indicator after the alert controller was presented, so for example you can do the following.

Replace this line:

```
ViewController.present(pending, animated: true, completion: completionHandler)
```

With this:

```
ViewController.present(pending, animated: true, completion: {
    // update frame here:
    indicator.frame = CGRect(x: (pending.view.frame.width/2) - 25 , y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    // and manually call completionHandler:
    completionHandler()
})
```